# Network issues on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, realtek

I am becoming quite frustrated with my internet connection on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 xfce. The connection is quite unstable at times, symptoms are variable speeds and drop outs. when the instability appears I can ping google (for instance) & run speedtest-cli but web pages take ages to load or time out all together. I need to turn network off then on again to regain connection. I have done the network manager & networkd thing.
Here is my network card from lspci: Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43, NUMA node 0
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Memory at d0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
    Kernel modules: r8168
I have done study and tried both r8168 & r8169 drivers/ kernel module combinations.
Machine basics are AMD FX-6300 6 core processor, with 8G ram. The ethernet controller is on the motherboard.
Any assistance would be most welcome as I am tearing my hair out here.
Oh, by the way my router is too far away for direct hard wire so i have a wifi to ethernet device (Dlink DAP1360) to derive my connection.

Comment: can you reproduce the symptoms on windows?

Comment: Don't have access to windows I'm afraid. I have tried several browsers (Palemoon, Chrome, Chromium) and on another OS (MX Linux) which I have as dual boot on my box. I also tried from Manjaro on virtualbox but of course the virtual network is still using my physical network. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: well if you can't rule out the ISP or network quality, it's seems like jumping to conclusions to blame ubuntu, no?

Comment: I hope it didn't sound like blaming Ubuntu, I do actually suspect network quality or ethernet device, but just needed some guidance to help isolate things.

Comment: I have also noted that my smart phone and wife's iPad have very few issues using wifi from the same router.

Comment: like I said. running a windows on that machine would be very conclusive. (yeah the ipad and the phone teaches us nothing, their hardware seems without fault)

Comment: OK, I will probably try windows in virtualbox first, I see what you mean, if it is good we can rule out the ethernet device

Comment: but like you said in virstualisation it will be running through the potentially blamable ubuntu ethernet driver. therefore results won't matter. you need a physical boot of windows on that machine to be able to draw any conclusions.

Comment: Agreed, I  now have an iso of windows 10, will install on spare hard drive tomorrow...watch this space

Comment: OMG! what a mission to create a bootable windows flash drive with Ubuntu. Ended up using Rufus on a windows virtual machine. I now have a bootable usb device ( have started install to test it, then aborted) will start full install very soon.

Comment: Finally got windows 10 working on an ssd installed on my rig. So far, it would appear the windows driver for realtek r8168 ethernet controller is superior. I am continuing testing to be conclusive.

Comment: Reinstalled r8168-dkms (again) and my network seems stable at the moment when I run Ubuntu 18.04.2. Streaming is the best it has ever been. Will probably close this after another few days of testing.

Comment: huh ok so the problem cannot be reproduced anymore?

Comment: I have had a few drop outs but connectivity is far better now. I am blaming them on my poor network connection (external)I can't fully explain it but after running windows driver on the ethernet port the performance on ubuntu seems to be better? go figure?

Comment: One more test: I am running the r8169 in kermel module for Linux 4.15.0-52 kernel for a while then switch back to r8168 to find out which driver is the best for my ethernet controller ,

Comment: Currently speeds are good enough for worry free surfing and there is no packet loss when doing ping tests.

Comment: okay, I'm glad there was a solution!

Comment: r8168 seems to be the better driver for my on board Realtek ethernet controller, I will stick with this for now.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @tatsu, I believe your push to ask me to try windows was useful and made me look at the problem slightly differently. I will go with the Windows comparison and re-installation of the correct driver as a probable solution.

Comment: How can my question be set to answered or closed please?

Comment: I have to make an answer for you to mark as the correct one. I'll do that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try reinstalling ubuntu or testing it on a windows to see if that fixes the problem.